# How to wait on an async.timeseries()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
    // do stuff
}   

async.timesSeries(100, myFunction);

doSomethingElse();
```

The problem is that doSomethingElse() is executing before every execution in async.timesSeries() has finished. Sorry for my ineptitude at NodeJS, but does anyone know a quick and easy fix for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[`async.timesSeries()`](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#timesSeries) returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) when the callback parameter is omitted, so just register `doSomethingElse` as the continuation using [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
async.timesSeries(100, myFunction).then(doSomethingElse);
```